# How to get a return value from socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am working with `node.js` and `socket.io`, 
and I want to get a variable but it throws an error.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    test = 1;
})

console.log(test) // ReferenceError: test is not defined
```

What I tried

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    return test = 1;
})
```

Expected result

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    test = 1;
})
console.log(test) // expected reslut test = 1
```

Comment: Hi Lou and welcome, keep in mind that on Stackoverflow, questions are supposed to be asked in english. I translated your post, hopping it dont get deleted before accepted.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code.

**1. Javascript is asynchronous by nature. So the control won't wait for your event to be fired before moving on to the next line.**

How it is related to your problem ?

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    test = 1;
})

console.log(test)
```

Here the function (where you are assigning `test=1`) will only execute when the `connection` event is fired. So the javascript engine would register your `io.sockets.on(...)` and then move on to the next line of execution i.e `console.log(test)`

Now since, the event is not fired yet, no value is assigned to `test`

**2. variable `test`  is not accessible to `console.log(test)`**

Assuming you are not in `strict` mode, `test` would get ***hoisted*** when the line `test = 1` gets executed, after that it, it would be available, however by the time `console.log(test)` gets executed, `test=1` hasn't executed yet(point #1), so the reference error.

So I suggest the you put your `console.log` statement code within the body of the anonymous function.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    test = 1;
    console.log(test);
})
```

Comment: I need to get the test variable out of the block